# Typical usage of node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am a quite new to node js and have done some homework in reading the docs, building a small app and went through some blogs posts. But now i'm looking for some typical use cases for a node application.

An example or a scenario will do.

Can someone help me with this?

Thanks.

Comment: A chat room? Any kind of simple webservices? Just watch this video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jo_B4LTHi3I from the creator of node_js it will teach you the "spirit" of node_js.

Comment: Efficient AJAX-enabled Content Management System with extensive file-sharing and interactivity.

Comment: [Read the 1-liner descriptions of the projects built with node.js on the node.js wiki](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Projects,-Applications,-and-Companies-Using-Node)

Comment: Node.js is perfect for website scraping, because of its speed. Here is an article. http://blog.dtrejo.com/scraping-made-easy-with-jquery-and-selectorga

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's really useful to build APIs that power mobile apps. At [i.TV](http://i.tv), we created an API with node.js to power our [iPhone App](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/i.-tv/id290338603?mt=8) that helps people know what's on TV. We use it because it scales really well and it's fun to program in JavaScript :)

LinkedIn chose Node.js to power their mobile app for similar reasons:
http://venturebeat.com/2011/08/16/linkedin-node/

Answer (score 0):

See http://corp.klout.com/blog/2011/10/the-tech-behind-klout-com/ or a long list at  https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Projects,-Applications,-and-Companies-Using-Node.

Node.js is stupendous with its single-thread-for-all-connection approach where each packet received is notified as event which is then handle by callback. Basically with node.js, you achieve a high level of concurrency without much multi-threading blues.

Also, when not to use node.js and why - http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.javascript.nodejs/30957.